# SevenZipSharp ExtractARchive decided wrong format

Tags: c#, .net, sevenzipsharp

I am using sevenzipsharp and I have a lot of archives that are msi, rar, iso and more formats that ExtractArchive decided it is TAR and because of that failed to extract them.
The archives can be extracted via the 7zip gui.
So I am sure the archives are OK.

Here is my extract code:

```
SevenZipExtractor.SetLibaryPath(pathTo7Z.dll)
using(SevenZipExtractor extr = new SevenZipExtractor(pathToFile)) 
{
extr.extractArchive(PathaToUnzipTo) 
}
```

SevenZipArchiveException is thrown on extractArchive:
invalid archive: open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong password was provided? 
If your archive is an exotic one, it is possible that SevenZipSharp has no signature for its format and thus decided it is TAR by mistake.

The archive is not password protect, and it is not TAR, and the archive can be extracted via 7zip gui.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same with simple .zip archives. Even enumerating the file list failed with that exception.

I downgraded to 7-zip version 16.04 and then it worked.